# How to properly duplicate an object given its shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I'm trying to make a duplicate of an object of a custom class `Event`. I have a shared pointer to the object that I've obtained from its allocation:

```
std::shared_ptr<Event> e = std::make_shared<Event>();
```

In order to get a true duplicate of `e` (not just a copy of the pointer) I've tried:

```
std::shared_ptr<Event> o = std::make_shared<Event>(*e);
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way as it seems that if I delete `e` it also deletes `o`...

Btw, I haven't defined a copy constructor `Event::Event(const Event &orig)` but in my understanding this is not necessary as the compiler provides a default copy constructor. The event class only contains variables and no further pointers.

Comment: It seems that `e` also deletes `o`? How so? You can add a destructor with a print statement to see what is happening.

Comment: You can put log in your Event destructor. for example std::cout.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`std::make_shared` is just a simple template function that creates the objects, passing all arguments to the constructor :

```
template<class T, class... Args>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args)
{
  return shared_ptr<T>( new T( std::forward<Args>( args )... ) );
}
```

In your particular case :

```
std::shared_ptr<Event> o = std::make_shared<Event>(*e);
```

the object is copied.

If your code is such :

```
void foo() {
    // create new object using default constructor
    std::shared_ptr<Event> e = std::make_shared<Event>();
    // create new object using copy constructor constructor
    std::shared_ptr<Event> o = std::make_shared<Event>(*e);
}
```

then of course both objects are destroyed, when they go out of scope.

Comment: Does make_shared() necessarily copy with a new object? Or does it move the object when possible?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The second line in `foo()` creates a new object using copy constructor - it doesn't move

Answer (score 10):

What you tried should work correctly, **if** the dynamic type of `*e` is `Event`, and not some class derived from `Event`. (If `*e` is actually an object derived from `Event` then you will create a new `Event` (not the derived type) as a copy of the base class part of `*e` i.e. you will "slice" `*e`).

Since you create `e` using `make_shared<Event>()` you know that in this case it really is an `Event`, so `std::make_shared<Event>(*e)` should make a new `shared_ptr` that owns a copy of `*e`.

Comment: I am having the problem you're describing. How would I create a copy of the shared_ptr to Base class from another shared_ptr to Base class, while retaining the fact that it is actually a Derived class?

Comment: My best solution so far is:
'code'
std::shared_ptr<Base> newBase;
Derived copiedJob = *static_cast<Derived*>(obj.mp_base.get());
  newBase = std::make_shared<Base>(copiedJob);
'\code'

Comment: @IronAttorney use `\`` for inline code markup, not 'code'. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting